# How to add overflow menu to empty actvity. I'm using android studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create and overflow menu . I have tried many tutorials but i failed to understand most of them. Can anyone please explain how to create overflow menu.

Comment: The basic Activity template contains the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a `your_menu.xml` inside **menu** folder inside **res**

*your_menu.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
       android:id="@+id/your_menu_id"
       android:title="menu example"></item>
</menu>
```

then in activity you can override `onCreateOptionsMenu` to show menu like below

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and finally onclick for menu items will be handled inside `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.your_menu_id: {
             //Perform your click operation
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```